# Git checkout single directory through Chef

Tags: git, chef-infra, git-sparse-checkout

Is there a way of doing an sparse checkout with Chef and its [`git` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html)? Or what is the best way to accomplish the equivalent of that?

As doing a sparse checkout requires modifying a file in the `.git` folder before doing the pull, I don't find a way of having the `git` resource configure the repository but not attempting to pull before I can edit that file. If I wait until the end of the `git` resource execution, then the total number of files of the tip of the branch will be already downloaded.

For reference this is what I'd otherwise do if I were doing a bash script:

```
git init <my_repo>
cd <my_repo>
git remote add origin <my_repos_url>
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo "my_directory/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull --depth=1 origin master
```

Question also posted here: https://discourse.chef.io/t/sparse-checkout-with-git-resource/11834

Comment: Please don't immediately cross post like that (though props for at least mentioning it). Most of us that do volunteer support already watch both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported really. Your best bet is probably to use an `execute`/`bash` resource do everything except the actual pull, and then put a normal `git` resource after that since it should obey the settings once set up.